# Returning a PHP arrays parent indexes when given a child index

Tags: php

I've been struggling with writing some elegant code that will return a PHP arrays parent indexes when given a child index. Perhaps this is best illustrated via example. Below we have a multi-dimensional array:

```
$array = array(
    'Level 1a' => array(
        'Level 2a' => array(
            'Level 3a' => array(
                'Level 4a' => array(

                )
            )
        ),
    ),
    'Level 1b' => array(
        'Level 2b' => array(
            'Level 3b' => array(
                'Level 4b' => array(
                    'Level 5b' => array()
                )
            )
        ),
    ),
    'Level 1c' => array(
        'Level 2c' => array(
            'Level 3c' => array(
                'Level 4c' => array(

                )
            )
        ),
        'Level 2d' => array(
            'Level 3e' => array(
                'Level 4e' => array(

                )
            )
        ),
        'Level 2f' => array(
            'Level 3g' => array(
                'Level 4h' => array(

                )
            )
        ),
    ),
);
```

Now I'd like to get an index such as Level 4c and have it return its parents:

```
$return = array(
    'Level 1c' => array(
        'Level 2c' => array(
            'Level 3c' => array(
                'Level 4c' => array(

                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

The best I've come up with thus far is the following function which will return it in string form, sort of...

```
function getIndexesParents($needle,$haystack,$parentKey=false,$debug=''){

    foreach($haystack as $index => $child){

        echo '@'.$index.' parentKey is "'.$parentKey.'"<br/>';
        if( $parentKey == false ){
            $parentKey = $index;
            echo 'New parentKey is "'.$parentKey.'"<br/>';
        }
        else{
            $parentKey.= '->'.$index;
        }

        if( $index == $needle ){
            return $parentKey;
        }
        else if( is_array($child) && count($child) > 0){
            echo "Going into next array under parentKey '$parentKey'<br/>";
            $result = getIndexesParents($needle,$child,$parentKey,'recursion');
            if( $result == false ){
                $parentKey = false;
            }
            else{
                return $result;
            }
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This will return "Level 1c->Level 2c->Level 3c->Level 4c" I'm building of this to hack together a solution, but frankly the code is ugly and difficult to read. So can anyone solve this?

Comment: I realized when looking through my old answers that I'd misunderstood your goal with this. I assume it's much too late for it to be useful to you, but I edited the answer to add something more like what I think you were trying to get.

Answer (score 0):

This uses basically the same logic as yours to generate the string, but I think it's a little more compact.  Whether or not it's ugly and difficult to read is in the eye of the beholder, I suppose.

```
function get_path($array, $target, $path = "") {
   if (is_array($array)) {
      foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
         if ($key == $target) {
            return $path ? "$path->$key" : $key;
         }
         $branch = get_path($value, $target, $path ? "$path->$key" : $key);
         if ($branch) {
            return $branch;
         }
      }
   }
};
```

---

I misunderstood this when I originally answered it; I thought you were just trying to get a shorter way to get the string representation of the path. This one should return the actual array path (or `null` if the target key is not found).

```
function get_path($subject, $target) {
    if (is_array($subject)) {
        if (isset($subject[$target])) return $subject;
        else {
            foreach ($subject as $key => $value) {
                $result = get_path($value, $target);
                if ($result) return [$key => $result];
            }
        }       
    }
}
```